# Symfony2: update breaks mapped false validation

Tags: php, validation, symfony

While using 2.3.4 I built a form with an unmapped field.  The form behaved as expected. No validation was applied to the unmapped field.  After an update to 2.3.6 today (from experiments with stable and dev versions) the unmapped field generates the validation error

> isHead: ERROR: This value is not valid.

in `$form->getErrorsAsString()`

#### Edit 3: use case

A household consists of a collection of members.  When the household is created, at least one member must exist and is designated head of household.  On occasion a different member needs to be designated head of household.  A non-mapped field isHead is constructed in the edit form with the value of the member's id.  This value is compared with the household entity's head_of_house_id to determine if a new head of household must be persisted.

#### Edit - added form field; edit 2 shows added constraint

```
    ->add('isHead', 'choice', array(
        'expanded' => true,
        'mapped' => false,
        'constraints' => array(new NotBlank(array('message' => 'This is a bogus value')))
    ))
```

#### composer.json: "minimum-stability": "stable",:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
    "beberlei/DoctrineExtensions": "*",
    "knplabs/knp-menu":"2.0.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle":"dev-master",
    "psliwa/pdf-bundle": "dev-master"
},
```

#### Output of composer update

```
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Updating twig/twig (dev-master 09c386b => v1.14.0)
    Checking out 224fc55635d544a2ec8edb3592be18db5a093f59

  - Updating doctrine/lexer (dev-master bc0e1f0 => v1.0)
    Checking out 2f708a85bb3aab5d99dab8be435abd73e0b18acb

  - Updating doctrine/inflector (dev-master 8b4b3cc => v1.0)
    Checking out 54b8333d2a5682afdc690060c1cf384ba9f47f08

  - Updating doctrine/collections (dev-master bcb5377 => v1.1)
    Checking out 560f29c39cfcfbcd210e5d549d993a39d898b04b

  - Updating doctrine/common (2.4.x-dev c94d6ff => v2.4.1)
    Checking out ceb18cf9b0230f3ea208b6238130fd415abda0a7

  - Updating symfony/symfony (v2.3.4 => v2.3.6)
    Checking out d0597156c4c03ceca039f6b7770a47397ba295f0

  - Updating symfony/icu (1.2.x-dev 98e197d => v1.2.0)
    Checking out 7299cd3d8d6602103d1ebff5d0a9917b7bc6de72

  - Updating incenteev/composer-parameter-handler (dev-master bc06242 => v2.0
    Checking out 2310d74a751025f02221e0faf69d31440df71b73

  - Updating doctrine/dbal (2.3.x-dev 59c310b => 2.3.4)
    Checking out 2a37b007dda8e21bdbb8fa445be8fa0064199e13

  - Updating doctrine/orm (2.3.x-dev 66d8b43 => 2.3.4)
    Checking out a41b02c080114c0de3da4ee9fba61f7d18fae7d0

  - Updating beberlei/doctrineextensions (dev-master bed4645 => v0.1)
    Checking out d38b081dbf826960bd9aad9d7dabed5164d3e7d3

  - Updating kriswallsmith/assetic (1.1.x-dev 1d671c5 => v1.1.2)
    Checking out 735cffd3982c6e8cdebe292d5db39d077f65890f

  - Updating symfony/assetic-bundle (2.3.x-dev 65bd076 => v2.3.0)
    Checking out 146dd3cb46b302bd471560471c6aaa930483dac1

  - Updating jms/metadata (dev-master 246d709 => 1.4.2)
    Checking out 246d7096801ce29b5aea30a1abf0277ccfb9f055

  - Updating jms/cg (dev-master 0d8d8c7 => 1.0.0)
    Checking out ce8ef43dd6bfe6ce54e5e9844ab71be2343bf2fc

  - Updating jms/aop-bundle (dev-master 93f41ab => 1.0.0)
    Checking out 8ef7db0043188f58da18f931937008f95b308921

  - Updating jms/di-extra-bundle (dev-master 01029f6 => 1.4.0)
    Checking out 7fffdb6c96fb922a131af06d773e1e6c5301d070

  - Updating phpoption/phpoption (dev-master 1c7e801 => 1.3.0)
    Checking out 1c7e8016289d17d83ced49c56d0f266fd0568941

  - Updating jms/parser-lib (dev-master d5961fa => 1.0.0)
    Checking out c509473bc1b4866415627af0e1c6cc8ac97fa51d

  - Updating zendframework/zend-memory (dev-master 7005247 => 2.2.4)
    Checking out 700524702bc3b6142107eac9c71f1b56236b3cd0

  - Updating zendframework/zend-stdlib (dev-master d8013ca => 2.2.4)
    Checking out 7c87ce4e840957596bf3401fa4ae4fb0355682e2

  - Updating zendframework/zend-eventmanager (dev-master f325fee => 2.2.4)
    Checking out f325feef4e1a19b873936e5b116980fbe88dd176

  - Updating zendframework/zend-servicemanager (dev-master e05c29f => 2.2.4)
    Checking out e05c29f8d7da6e2c26d2d8b334324932a73afa78

  - Updating zendframework/zend-cache (dev-master fa5343b => 2.2.4)
    Checking out 64044faa106710a6dd2735a06b5034cd9cb2dc67

  - Updating zendframework/zendpdf (dev-master 6efcb51 => 2.0.2)
    Checking out 041f90c339cff63a3c4d03a28ef1ea5188059793

  - Updating psliwa/php-pdf (dev-master 51d9be9 => 1.2.1)
    Checking out 2ab60bd35f5095826ef28df56c8c3a08031201fe

  - Updating jdorn/sql-formatter (dev-master 51a660e => v1.2.9)
    Checking out bd1f09133f6dbbe0713856910e58ea9480c2be58

  - Updating monolog/monolog (dev-master 8e5a671 => 1.6.0)
    Checking out f72392d0e6eb855118f5a84e89ac2d257c704abd

  - Installing knplabs/knp-menu-bundle (dev-master 1b07578)
    Cloning 1b07578738d3425c09cfbd153276382388994f46
```

Comment: I know it's possible to back off on the symfony version (and I've done that), but shouldn't a stable version not break an application in this way? How does this get fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably happening due to the Symfony team fixing a bug in regards to `choice` types and the `expanded` option.

> [**9542d72**: [Form] Fixed expanded choice field to be marked invalid when unknown choices are submitted](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/9542d72dc049bad180b56ece4619ef9773f4cabf)

This was merged and released in Symfony **2.3.5**.

Since you do not specify the `choices` option, the value you specify is not a valid choice and therefore correctly fails.

From what I can see from the name of the field, you want a `checkbox` type field.

Comment: It needs to be a radio field.  What work-around exists, if any?

Comment: Then if it needs to be a radio field, specify the available [`choices`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices). Right now, your code is building a *choice* field with no valid answer.

Comment: So all I need to do, it seems, is figure out how to use the GreaterThanOrEqual validator in the form type, 'cuz the value needs to be >= 0.  No example found yet!

Comment: Even after adding a simple constraint (see edit above) the field fails validation.  Error message is unchanged, which suggests the validator is ignored.

Comment: No, you need to specify the choices option. See the link in my comment above.

Comment: With this painfully obvious, and after traveling a spaghetti route, I ended up passing an array of member ids (with each id as its own key) to the field as the field's choices.  So I have accepted your answer.  Many thanks.